# how to show image at center of tab?

Tags: android

I have created a tab in android which displays only images (does not contain any text ), I want the image to be displayed at the center of the tab .There are multiple tabs, each containing images, but the problem is that the image is not displayed at the center of each tab.

here is my xml

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs"
             />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#000000" >
        </TabWidget>
    </RelativeLayout>

</TabHost>
```

setting image in code:

```
newsTab.setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.news)).setContent(
                new Intent(RestauActivity.this, NewsActivity.class));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1)- Create a layout file with name report_tabs.xml or any name you like.

In report_tabs use this code.

```
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/layout_tabsLayout"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/btn_selector"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     >

     <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/img_icon"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
     />
    </LinearLayout>
```

2)- And use below code in your activity.

```
    Intent intent;
    tabhost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec tabspec;
    intent = new Intent().setClass(getApplicationContext(),xxxxx.class);

    tabspec = tabhost.newTabSpec("First");
    view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.report_tabs,
tabhost.getTabWidget(), false);

    imgtabF = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_icon);
    imgtabF.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_icon_selector);

    tabspec.setIndicator(view);
    tabspec.setContent(intent);
    tabhost.addTab(tabspec);
```

3)- Create a file with name tab_icon_selector in drawable for changing the icon on tab click like this:-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" 
          android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/medical_icon_unselect"    
     />
     <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true" 
     android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/medical_icon_sel" /> 
     <!-- Focused states -->
     <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" 
     android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/medical_icon_sel" />
     <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true" 
     android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/medical_icon_sel" /> 
     <!-- Pressed -->
     <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/> 
     </selector>
```

Now you can create your custom Tab bar and your image icon will be in center of the tab.